# can we convert PDF containing Embedded Fonts to NonEmbedded(standard fonts) PDF document using Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I have tried the below commands

```
$ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf inputwithembeddedType1.PDF

$ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dEmbedAllFonts=false -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf inputwithembeddedType1.PDF
```

In the first case the output is correct with AdobeReader but it is still embeddedfonts, and hence unable to parse into **my application as a limitation of not supporting embedded PDF fonts.**

The second command works and created a PDF file while not able to open in AdobeReader as well as my application.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got my answer by a little research, making use of **dNoOutputFonts**. This is working well for me

```
ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dNoOutputFonts -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf inputwithembeddedType1.PDF
```